# How to auto append newline at the end of a file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, scanf

I am newbie and have a C - Linux program that read a number of variable lines like this:

```
12 34 56 78
3 4 7 900
...
%d %d %d %d
...
1 2 3 4
```

The function I've written so far is like this:

```
void Import(const char* path_of_file)
{
  FILE *cfile = fopen(path_of_file, "r");
  int lines = 0;
  //I copied it from another question
  while (EOF != (fscanf(cfile,"%*[^/n]"), fscanf(cfile, "%*c"))) ++lines;
  fclose(cfile);
  cfile = fopen(path_of_file, "w");
  ...
  for( i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    ...
    fscanf(cfile, "%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    ...
  }
  ...
  //Of course it will return something, but it shouldn't matter here
  fclose(cfile);
}
```

But may be because the text file is created in Windows or some thing, it doesn't always end with a newline, and so my program frequently miss the last line.

Is there anyway to automatic append a newline at the end of file if it's not there? Or better, is there any way to read the last line without that newline? A example function based on the one above will be very good.

Comment: if you're looking to use a Windows formatted file on a linux system, you may want to try the command-line tool dos2unix to fix the newlines

Comment: If you want to read lines, use fgets instead of scanf. If you have to worry about newline or not newline at the end of the file, you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a line, and `sscanf` to parse it. Much easier handling.

Comment: @user3288829 Actually, it's an assignment, so a tool is out of options, it must be ran within the program.

Comment: The way you calculate the number of lines is a bit strange (why `/n`?). But if it works most of the time, you can just overestimate the number by iterating `n+1` times and just exit the loop if `scanf` can't read anything.

Comment: @Henrik Sorry,I am a newbie, can you write a small program use fgets, and why it will read that last line but fscanf can not?

Comment: @Pavel As I stated above, the count lines code is borrowed from another question, to be honest I didn't really understand the "%*[^/n]" and how two function can lie on the while clause with a "," between them.

Comment: is this where you got it from? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278845/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-count-the-newlines-in-an-ascii-file then check again

Comment: @Pavel Yes, yes. That where I got it. And I have to pre-allocate a shared memory to store those number (in the ...), so try the 'n+1' step mean that I will have to reallocate all of it.

Comment: @Tr1et Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383449/#22383633

Comment: @Tr1et re: "with a , between them" see [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Both expressions are evaluated but only the result of the right-hand-side (the 2nd fscanf) is returned to the while clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Pavel, I have never read the other answer in that post, my fault for only read the Accepted answer. After read all those posts, I chosen to use this code to count the line, it can avoid the problem above:

```
int n = 0;
int pc = EOF;
int c;
while ((c = getc(cfile)) != EOF) {
  if (c == '\n')
    ++n;
  pc = c;
}
if (pc != EOF && pc != '\n')
  ++n;
```

Sorry for my stupidness.